# Change a fillet radius to zero

Tags: edit-mode, sverchok

This seems so simple, I'm embarrassed to ask, but is there an easy way to change a fillet radius? If you look at the attached file, you should be able to see where I've highlighted a 5 unit radius; I just want it to become a mitre as opposed to a fillet (i.e. a fillet of radius zero). For the next step, it might be nice to control this radius (and all similar radii) parametrically in Sverchok, but perhaps that's for another day.

[image]

Comment: I don't have Sverchok, but could this help: (1) Select Curve (2) Edit Mode (3) 3D Viewport Menu: *Curve > Set Spline Type > Poly*

Comment: @Leander OK - that works! Unfortunately, it breaks the sweep/loft that's attached to this path. Still, maybe it's a start...

Comment: Quick workaround would be to just add extra bezier control points with very short handles, forming a sharp corner.